# How to override __getitem__ when it's a class method?

Tags: python, abstract-class

```
class Custom(type):
    @classmethod
    def __getitem__(cls, item):
        raise NotImplementedError("")

    @classmethod
    def test(cls):
        print("class custom : test")

class Book(metaclass=Custom):
    Note = 0
    Pad = 1

    Name = { Note : "Note", Pad : "Pad"}

    @classmethod
    def __getitem__(cls, item):
        return Book.Name[item]

    @classmethod
    def test(cls):
        print("class book: test")
```

My intention is to have

```
Book[Book.Note] returns "Note"
```

It seems __getitem__() is not overrideable, unlike test(). How do I make it work ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using a metaclass here. This isn't strictly inheritance: you've defined *the class* of the class `Book` as `Custom`, whereas it used to be `type`. Because magic methods like `__getitem__` are looked up directly on the class, and not on the instance, indexing `Book[whatever]` will actually call the `__getitem__` method of the class of `Book`, which happens to be `Custom`.

> My intention is to have
>
> ```
> Book[Book.Note]
> ```
>
> returns "Note"

In that case, you should make the class of `Book` implement `__getitem__` such that it returns `"Note"`. Since the class of `Book` is `Custom`, this is where the change needs to be made:

```
class Custom(type):
    def __getitem__(cls, item):
        return cls.Name[item]
    ...

class Book(metaclass=Custom):
    ... # as is, although you don't need the @classmethod __getitem__

Book[Book.Note] # "Note"
Book[1]         # "Pad"
```

Comment: @user1502776 That's odd. I'm using Python 3 myself and it works. Let me see if I can put together a demo.

Comment: Your explanation demonstrates profound understanding of Python workings. Could you please recommend a book to read on ..?

Comment: @user1502776 I wouldn't say I have a rock solid understanding of Python, even after a long time using it, but if I had to suggest anything I'd suggest reading the docs; they're pretty good.